# STM32WB - sensor data sent via BLE and saved on SD card (SPI)

Tags: stm32, spi, clock, sd, bluetooth-low-energy

I have an STM32WB and I am trying to get the data from some pressure, temperature and humidity sensors through DMA and send them to my Android via BT, while at the same time saving it as well on a SD card with SPI.

Both programs work quite well separately, both for SD and for BT (I used the Hands On from STM where you send random temperature data to the app), however when I put them together neither of them works. Here I think I lack the knowledge of setting the Clock Source.

For my SD card and receiving of sensor data, I normally use the PLLCLK with 32 MHz on CPU1 and 16 MHz on CPU2. However for the BT app, I used the HSE_SYS clock source with both CPUs on 32 MHz.

I can't seem the wrap my head around how to set the clock in order for both these functions to be able to work together.

Also as a second question would be: How do you suggest to implement the two functions in a same program? I want the data to be transmitted simultaneously via BT, while also storing the same sensor data on the SD card.

I notice that after I get to the UTIL_SEQ_Run function that starts my BT, everything else from main is ignored, so I cannot go for my SD card functions. How could I combine this? Does it have anything to do with the scheduler? I am not so sure how to have these two tasks run in parallel.

Comment: Your sensor task probably doesn't care about the clock, and ST's timing functions are clock agnostic, so use the clock setup for BLE.  Yes, you will have to understand the program structure/flow of the BLE code and work within it.  Unfortunately your question is too broad to fit here.  Work on really understanding what the BLE program does and augment it slightly - first blink an LED, then read a sensor, etc.

Comment: I figured out the clock part, now my BLE is working on PLLCLK.
I am trying to do what you have suggested, reading a sensor through the BLE code. 
Do you have any suggestions on how to implement the DMA with the BLE? I was thinking about using the scheduler for having it within a task and writing it into the template_server_app.c

As a second idea: should I move all of the sensor reading functions from main.c to the other file, or is this too sloppy and I should look for another option?

Comment: Again this really does not fit within the guidelines of this site.  You probably do not need to use DMA - while it can work it tends to be an unecessary complication except in cases of exceptionally high data rate.